# JavaScript показывает количество дней от и до определённой даты. Нужно добавить условие

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт, который показывает два числа, количество дней от определённой даты, и количество дней до определённой будущей даты.

JavaScript:

```
d0 = new Date('Nov 26, 2012');
d1 = new Date();
d2 = new Date('Nov 26, 2016');
d3 = new Date();
dt = (d1.getTime() - d0.getTime()) / (1000*60*60*24);
ds = (d3.getTime() - d2.getTime()) / (1000*60*60*24);
document.write(Math.round(dt) + ' / ' + Math.round(ds));
```

Необходимо прописать условие чтобы будущее число становилось крассным и жирным при достижении определённого предела.
К примеру сейчас в выходе мы имеем число -71 (-70), но как только число будет меньше 20 то сработает условие присваивания  и число в выводе будет крассным и жирным. Чем проще тем лучше.

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собственно, всё, что вам нужно сделать - добавить нужную проверку и форматирование.
Если сделать код более читаемым, это может выглядеть как-то так:

```
var past = + new Date('Nov 26, 2012'), // автоматическое приведение к таймстампу
    future = + new Date('Sep 26, 2016'), // аналог (new Date('xxx')).getTime();
    now = + new Date(),
    featuredTimeStyles = 'color: red; font-weight: bold',
    millisecondsInADay = 1000*60*60*24,
    daysPassed, daysLeft, daysPassedFormatted, daysLeftFormatted;

daysPassed = Math.round((now - past) / millisecondsInADay);
daysLeft = Math.round((now - future) / millisecondsInADay);

daysPassedFormatted = daysPassed;
daysLeftFormatted = daysLeft >= -20 ?
    '<span style="' + featuredTimeStyles + '">' + daysLeft + '</span>' :
    daysLeft;

document.write(daysPassedFormatted + ' / ' + daysLeftFormatted);
```

Здесь ещё много чего можно улучшить, но смысл, думаю, понятен.

Comment: Алексей, благодарю. Решение более чем удовлетворяет использование. Скрипт необходим для отслеживания даты окончания оплаты за доменные имена.